# What is meant by latched comparator?

Tags: comparator

What is meant by latched comparator? And how can we identify if the given comparator is latched?

Comment: It's a comparator followed by a latch. Does it have a clock or enable input?

Comment: Generally for a comparator, I didn't specifically look into one comparator

Comment: this can help ?   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDhVA42luq0

Comment: @Antonio51, could you describe what your link points to?

Comment: Googling ... I found this, but did not see all the video, only "title of video" <<<Designing a Latching Comparator Circuit>>> and schematic. It seems very unusual. Don't know the behavior for now. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iauUE.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoBvZ.png

Comment: If not useful ... I delete